# How do I check if an item is in an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have to do a program that creates an array in which to put only positive numbers, but I do not know how to verify that the element "a[j]" is not already in the array "b". I looked for methods (like "contains") but the program gives me error.

```
public class YourClassNameHere {
    public static int[] main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1,-2,3,-5};
        int[] b = new int[a.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
            if(a[j] > 0)
            if(!(Arrays.asList(b).contains(a[j]))) // ?
                b[i] = a[j];
        return b;
    }
}
```

In line 8:

```
 Error: cannot find symbol
      symbol:   variable Arrays
      location: class YourClassNameHere
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: To start, please rewrite your code with proper usage of braces and whitespace. The way you are currently writing your code is unsafe and prone to errors.

Comment: This code works fine.Please add the error

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Are you import `java.util.*`? Use main method as void return type.

Answer (score 1):

Regular array doesn't have method `contains()`. Also you can't use `Arrays.asList` with  primitive because Java's generics don't support primitive types like `List<int>`. You could use `Integer[] b` instead of `int[] b`, then your example will work fine.

But with primitive types you can use stream api like:

```
Arrays.stream(b).anyMatch(value -> value == a[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 1, -2, 3, -5 };
        //to store all positive values
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(a).filter(number -> (number > 0)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //to remove duplicate values  
        for (Integer element : list) {
            if (!newList.contains(element)) {
                newList.add(element);
            }
        }
        // convert to array
        int[] newArr = new int[newList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++)
            newArr[i] = newList.get(i);

        for (int x : newArr)
            System.out.print(x + " ");

    }

}
```

Output :

```
1 3
```